# How to implement a function that'll parse Strings from .txt files?

Tags: python-2.7

It seems quite simple and I think that I am on the right track but I cannot find a specific version of my question through the search.

I have a function which needs to calculate values. The data comes from a bunch of .txt files, which are different in name as follows:
data_0.txt, data_1.txt, .... data_n.txt. 
My function needs to use two different data files each time so it is important that I can distinguish between them. I was therefore thinking that I could do something like this:

```
def calculator(name, no_1, no_2):
    name_1 = name + '_%no_1.txt'
    name_2 = name + '_%no_2.txt'
    .....
```

However, I cannot get this to work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Would `name_1 = name + '_' + no_1 + '.txt'` not work?

Comment: I tried that but no_1 is an integer and even with str(no_1) it gives error, saying that int and string are not compatible.

Comment: Found the answer. I had declared the name wrong.
So 'name_1 = name + '_' + str(no_1) + '.txt'' works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

declare a files list:

files = []

Do a for:

```
for i in xrange(1,n):
    files.append("data_" + i + ".txt")
```

I think this will solve. If it works, in the end you'll have a list of your text file names. You can access and distinguish them based on index from 0 to n-1